# Mercenaries and how/when to hire them

Tags: atlantica-online

I read an article on the Atlantica front page about the [Puppeteer Rin](http://atlantica.nexon.net/News/detail?boardNo=1000&contentNo=00EW2). I found one part very interesting:

> Rin can be recruited during the Bunraku Festival event, June 27, 2012 through July 26, 2012.

I have not played games where the recruitment of a unit (mercenary in this case) is dependent on real world time. Is there a list of the various known mercs in Atlantica with

- times of the year that they can be hired
- cost or other requirements to hire
- difficulty to acquire for a new or beginning character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Recruitment
>
> Rin can be recruited during the Bunraku Festival event, June 27, 2012
>   through July 26, 2012. No additional information beyond this is known
>   at the moment.

Is what Nexon said. And of what I've seen so far, it's the only event based merc.